# CTreeCtrl is not displaying all the items in a node

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, treeview, treenode

I am using CtreeCtrl and just struck with a new case which i haven't faced before..

The case is ..

I add more than 2000 items in a particular node .. but i can see only 200+ items under the node..(each time i get different counts displayed) ( ??? )

`TreeControl->InsertItem(server,icon,icon,TempParent,TVI_SORT);`

So what is wrong here..? Should i need to set any property here..? or Is there any max limit in adding items in the node...??

I add more than 2000 items in a particular node .. but i can see only 200+ items under the node..(each time i get different counts displayed) ( ??? )

Comment: Did you check the return code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no property you can set. I just created simple project and added 6 branches, each containing 2500 nodes and have no problem displaying all.

It must be something in your code, that prevents a proper display.

Two choices:
Create simple project and add large amount of items or post your project for download to see what is going on.

I cannot see any other way to help you.